# SQL how does "and" operator work, when both fields are indexed?

Tags: sql

Consider this SQL

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM places 
WHERE (latitude BETWEEN 10 AND 20) AND (longitude BETWEEN 30 AND 40)
```

Now, `latitude` and `longitude` are **both** indexed. How is SQL performed under-the-hood?

Will it search rows satisfying each condition **separately**, then find the **intersection** of those rows? Such as

- Step 1: Find all rows satisfying condition1 `latitude BETWEEN 10 AND 20`.
- Step 2: Find all rows satisfying condition2 `longitude BETWEEN 30 AND 40`.
- Step 3: Find the intersection between the above 2 sets of rows.

If this is how it works, it can be very slow, because each condition can yield millions of rows, which is very memory-intensive already. Then we perform an **intersection** operation, which can be slow.

Can anyone explain is this is how the SQL works under-the-hood, or are there other optimizations?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags. Only tag with the database you are actually using.

Comment: If it is MySQL, it will use index only on one of the columns; because both are range conditions. The more selective column will be chosen for index.

Comment: Moreover, SQL is just a language. Every RDBMS has its own algorithms, storage implementation, different index tree structures etc implemented. so, there is no specific answer to your problem.

Comment: For this query, you would better create a composite index on *both* columns instead of one index on each column.

Comment: @Maria It depends on so many things: for starters, the database engine, the version of the engine, the available data operators, the selectivity of the columns. If you provide this information we can help you further.

Answer (score 1):

The default index in most (if not all) databases are B-trees.  For filters in a `where` clause and index seek (what you really want) can be used with:

- Initial equality conditions, assuming that the columns (or expressions if expression-based indexes are supported) are the initial keys in the index.
- One inequality.

Note:  some databases support skip-scan operations that slightly increase the flexibility here, but I am going to ignore that.

If you have multiple indexes that can be used for a query, then the optimizer chooses which one is best.

These rules basically tell you what happens  If you have two separate indexes on `latitude` and `longitude` then the optimizer will choose one of them.

If you have a compound index with `(latitude, longitude)` (for instance), then only the first key is used for locating the rows in the index.  The second key in the index will probably be used, but it will not affect the number of rows in the index.

All of this is meant to explain that standard indexing is not going to work well on your query.  There are alternatives, particularly a structure called R-trees.  Databases use these for GIS/spatial indexes.  If you need performance on this type of query, use a spatial index.